# how to get the TextRenderInfo from pdfpage in iText7

Tags: itext7

How to get the TextRenderInfo from the pdf page using the **iText 7**. I need to find if a text exists and derive the y coordinate of that pdf page. Any suggestions please?

Any options with..

```
ITextExtractionStrategy textStrategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
ITextExtractionStrategy locationStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
```

Comment: *"How to get the TextRenderInfo from the pdf page using the iText 7"* - Which `TextRenderInfo` exactly? Usually page content parsing results in very many instances of that class...

Answer (score 2):

Easy, 
implement ITextExtractionStrategy (or extend an existing implementation).
The interface has following method

```
@Override
public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {

     // you can first check the type of the event
     if (!type.equals(EventType.RENDER_TEXT))
        return;

     // now it is safe to cast
     TextRenderInfo renderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;
}
```

Once you have such an implementation, you need to use

```
MyCustomStrategy strategy = new MyCustomStrategy(); // this is the class I described earlier
PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(doc.getPage(pageNr), strategy);
```

Your custom ITextExtractionStrategy can then simply be programmed to store all TextRenderInfo objects. And offer a simply getter.